# Finding top N values for each group, 200 million rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas DataFrame which has around 200 million rows and looks like this:

```
UserID  MovieID  Rating
1       455      5
2       411      4
1       288      2
2       300      3
2       137      5
1       300      3

...
```

I want to get top N movies for each user sorted by rating in descending order, so for N=2 the output should look like this:

```
UserID  MovieID  Rating
1       455      5
1       300      3
2       137      5
2       411      4
```

When I try to do it like this, I get a 'memory error' caused by the 'groupby' (I have 8gb of RAM on my machine)

```
df.sort_values(by=['rating']).groupby('userID').head(2)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: sort would be costly and everything would be in memory, if possible go with minHeap (Obviously somehow you would need to go away from DF)?

Comment: @SMA sort actually finishes in 10 minutes and is not the problem (except for being relatively slow), it's only when I add the groupby part that it crashes.

Comment: 200 million is way beyond what pandas is capable of handling. Try using dask or spark.

Comment: Given that the sort works, you may be able to get away with using Numpy operations to replace the `groupby` (see the first section of my answer). If that fails, you're pretty much stuck with a batched solution (as suggested by Avi) or  a heavy-duty solution (as suggested by coldspeed).

Answer (score 3):

## Quick and dirty answer

Given that the sort works, you may be able to squeak by with the following, which uses a Numpy-based memory efficient alternative to the Pandas `groupby`:

```
import pandas as pd

d = '''UserID  MovieID  Rating
1       455      5
2       411      4
3       207      5
1       288      2
3        69      2
2       300      3
3       410      4
3       108      3
2       137      5
3       308      3
1       300      3'''
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(d), sep='\s+', index_col='UserID')

df = df.sort_values(['UserID', 'Rating'])

# carefully handle the construction of ix to ensure no copies are made
ix = np.zeros(df.shape[0], np.int8)
np.subtract(df.index.values[1:], df.index.values[:-1], out=ix[:-1])

# the above assumes that UserID is the index of df. If it's just a column, use this instead
#np.subtract(df['UserID'].values[1:], df['UserID'].values[:-1], out=ix[:-1])

ix[:-1] += ix[1:]
ix[-2:] = 1
ix = ix.view(np.bool)
print(df.iloc[ix])
```

Output:

```
        MovieID  Rating
UserID                 
1           300       3
1           455       5
2           411       4
2           137       5
3           410       4
3           207       5
```

## More memory efficient answer

Instead of a Pandas dataframe, for stuff this big you should just work with Numpy arrays (which Pandas uses for storing data under the hood). If you use an appropriate [structured array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/user/basics.rec.html), you should be able to fit all of your data into a single array roughly of size:

```
2 * 10**8 * (4 + 2 + 1)
1,400,000,000 bytes
or ~1.304 GB
```

which means that it (and a couple of temporaries for calculations) should easily fit into your 8 GB system memory.

Here's some details:

- The trickiest part will be initializing the structured array. You may be able to get away with manually initializing the array and then copying the data over:

  ```
  dfdtype = np.dtype([('UserID', np.uint32), ('MovieID', np.uint16), ('Rating', np.uint8)])
  arr = np.empty(df.shape[0], dtype=dfdtype)
  arr['UserID'] = df.index.values
  for n in dfdtype.names[1:]:
      arr[n] = df[n].values
  ```

  If the above causes an out of memory error, from the start of your program you'll have to build and populate a structured array instead of a dataframe:

  ```
  arr = np.empty(rowcount, dtype=dfdtype)
  ...
  adapt the code you use to populate the df and put it here
  ...
  ```
- Once you have `arr`, here's how you'd do the groupby you're aiming for:

  ```
  arr.sort(order=['UserID', 'Rating'])

  ix = np.zeros(arr.shape[0], np.int8)
  np.subtract(arr['UserID'][1:], arr['UserID'][:-1], out=ix[:-1])
  ix[:-1] += ix[1:]
  ix[-2:] = 1
  ix = ix.view(np.bool)
  print(arr[ix])
  ```
- The above size calculation and `dtype` assumes that no `UserID` is larger than `4,294,967,295`, no `MovieID` is larger than `65535`, and no rating is larger than `255`. This means that the columns of your dataframe can be `(np.uint32, np.uint16, np.uint8)` without loosing any data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep working with pandas, you can divide your data into batches - 10K rows at a time, for example. You can split the data either after loading the source data to the DF, or even better, load the data in parts.

You can save the results of each iteration (batch) into a dictionary keeping only the number of movies you're interested with:

```
{userID: {MovieID_1: score1, MovieID_2: s2, ... MovieID_N: sN}, ...}
```

and update the nested dictionary on each iteration, keeping only the best N movies per user.

This way you'll be able to analyze data much larger than your computer's memory